# Azure Data Factory - how to save the rowCount of copied records in a file in ADLS Gen2 or to send this information to email as notification?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to save the output result of the rowsRead(source destination) and rowsCopied(sink destination) in a file in ADLS Gen2 or send it as an email notification.

[This is the output result I want to store in a file or send as email notification(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWsm1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number rows read and number of rows written from the Copy activity output.

[image]

To avoid complicate dynamic content in the web activity Body, first store these in two in a string variables.
For **rows read** use the below dynamic content.

```
@string(activity('Copy data1').output.rowsRead)
```

[image]

For **rows written** use the below expression

```
@string(activity('Copy data1').output.rowsCopied)
```

[image]

For mail, you can use logic apps. Use web activity to invoke logic app.

create a parameter for mail in pipeline.

[image]

**Web activity:**

[image]

In the Body of the web activity, give the below dynamic content.

```
{
"message" : "This is a custom dynamic message from your pipeline with run ID @{pipeline().RunId} and rows read are @{variables('rowsread')} and rows written are @{variables('rowswritten')}.",  
"dataFactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
"pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
"receiver" : "@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"
}
```

For logic app workflow, please go through this [Microsoft Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email) which has step by step explanation to send mail from ADF using logic app.

Comment: Thank you, @RakeshGovindula! I tested it and it works!